# IntelliJ terminal jdk setting

Tags: java, intellij-idea, terminal

I have a project in IntelliJ Idea that uses jdk 8. In my system I have many jdk installed for development. Every time I create a new terminal window inside IntelliJ, the latest system jdk (jdk 10) is used and not the project one (jdk 8 in this case) and I have to switch manually. Of course I realise the error only after some build which requires jdk 8 does not work properly.

Is there a possibility to set the jdk used in IntelliJ terminal?

Comment: any update on this for intellij community 2022.1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repost the answer of @yole from the comments. It is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Check Preferences->Tools->Terminal do determine the used shell implementation.

Change the shell path or change your environment settings with the used shell to take effect e.g. for setting `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`.

You can even use the "shell integration" flag to load a custom rc config file. Please check the IntelliJ documentation for this.

You are not able to use the configured projects JDK in a dynamic way. If you need this, please file an enhancement request to Jetbrains.

Comment: if I change the env settings these are system wide. I want only that the intellj terminal jdk mirrors the project settings.

Comment: You can use the "shell implementation" setting to provide a custom rc config file. See the IntelliJ documentation for more information on this. But IntelliJ is not able to pass some project configuration specific values to the forked terminal windows. You have to file an enhancement request to Jetbrains if you need something like that.

Comment: could you pls expand the concept _You can use the "shell implementation" setting to provide a custom rc config file_?  Then, if _IntelliJ is not able to pass some project configuration specific values to the forked terminal windows_,  **that is exactly what I need**, why should I _See the IntelliJ documentation for more information_ ?. I don't get it sorry..

Comment: The feature you're asking for does not exist. Here's one related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-199430

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the SDK version in project structure. You can change it through IntelliJ navigation top bar, by following this path:

File > Project Structure > Project tab > Project SDK

Comment: This is already set correctly as jdk 8, the issue here is that this setting does not influence the jdk used in the terminal inside intellj

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles on this question, here is how I resolved a similar issue:

Maybe this is just my company's security*, but when a JDK is installed with an .exe, something like the following path is created and added to the root of the %path% variable:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

On that path you'll find a 'java' executable for the installed version of java.

The fix was to simply uninstall that version of java, via the system settings.

`*` I mean that I was unable to see the 'true' path variable, may have been my company's security.

Answer (score 0):

As per other answers - doesn't look like its supported but in the meantime I thought I would post a workaround that solves the poster's problem:

my solution is to create a shell script that launches with the terminal profile:

- check the existence of .idea directory in current working directory
- if it does then pull the configured name of the jdk from the misc.xml
- find the jdk directory under $home/.jdks where intellij installs them.
- add the found jdk bin directory to the head of the path in the current session

my solution is in powershell as I found it an interesting exercise to solve.  The same can be achieved in Unix as easily if not easier.

```
# $Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

$ideaDir = "./.idea"
if (Test-Path -Path $ideaDir)
{
    $jdksDir = "$Home\.jdks"
    $match = Select-String -Path "$ideaDir/misc.xml" -Pattern "project-jdk-name=`"(.*?)`" "
    $jdkName = $match.Matches.groups[1].value

    [array]$jdks = ls -Directory -Name $jdksDir
    $success = 0
    foreach( $jdk in $jdks) {
        if($jdk.Contains( $jdkName )) {
            $pathBlock = "$jdksDir\$jdk\bin"
            echo "adding $pathBlock to path"
            $env:Path = "$pathBlock;" + $env:Path
            $success = 1
            break
        }
    }
    if( $success -eq 0) {
        "failed to add jdk $jdkName to path"
    }
}
```

Some assumptions have been made here:

- jdks are installed via intellij and jdk names are defaulted (I tested with correto-18 and openjdk-21).
- I noticed is that workspace files are saved on exit, not on the change itself.  If you're swapping around quickly then it's not much of a solution.  If however you've got different projects on different jdks then it may make life easier.  You can paste the code into your powershell [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/creating-profiles?view=powershell-7.3) to execute on new terminal sessions